# error: no matching function for call to [...] note: template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation

```
template <int dim = 2>
class point {
private:
    std::array<double, dim> coords;
public:
    /* Constructors, destructor, some members [...] */
    template <typename operation_aux, int dim_aux> point<dim_aux>
        plus_minus_helper(const point<dim_aux>& op1, const point<dim_aux>& op2);
};

template <typename operation, int dim> point<dim>
    plus_minus_helper(const point<dim>& op1, const point<dim>& op2)
{
    /* Do all the calculations.
     * The algorithm is very similar for both addition and subtraction,
     * so I'd like to write it once
     */
}

template <int dim>
    point<dim> operator+(const point<dim>& op1, const point<dim>& op2)
{
    return plus_minus_helper<std::plus>(op1, op2);
}

template <int dim>
    point<dim> operator-(const point<dim>& op1, const point<dim>& op2)
{
    return plus_minus_helper<std::minus>(op1, op2);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv []) {
    point<2> Pt1(1, 2), Pt2(1, 7), Pt3(0, 0);

    Pt3 = Pt1 + Pt2;
    std::cout << Pt3(0) << " " << Pt3(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this code on GCC produces the following error

```
./test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘point<dim> operator+(const point<dim>&, const point<dim>&) [with int dim = 2]’:
./test.cpp:47:17:   required from here
./test.cpp:35:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘plus_minus_helper(const point<2>&, const point<2>&)’
     return plus_minus_helper<std::plus>(op1, op2);
                                                 ^
./test.cpp:35:49: note: candidate is:
./test.cpp:26:5: note: template<class operation, int dim> point<dim> plus_minus_helper(const point<dim>&, const point<dim>&)
     plus_minus_helper(const point<dim>& op1, const point<dim>& op2)
     ^
./test.cpp:26:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

It seems it is a problem with the instatiaton of the template, in fact the `-` operator does not produce any error.
I provided all the necessary types to instantiate the function, an operation and the dimension of the operators. The dimension is implicit in the parameters, and I don't think I passed conflicting parameters.
I'm trying to call the helper function passing to it the calculation to execute (addition or subtraction). I don't want to write the algorithm twice one time for addition and one time for subtraction, because they only differ by for the operation performed.
How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, that `std::plus`/`std::minus` are template classes. You should point, which instantiation of class you want to send, or if you can use C++14 - just `<>`, if you don't want to point, which instantiation compiler should use you can use `template template parameter`.

```
return plus_minus_helper<std::plus<>>(op1, op2);
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AoMur7IeZzG0XrDB)

Comment: Or alternatively, use template templates. This restricts to a certain signature however...